# How to save VF page with lightningstylesheets as PDF to lead record

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a VF page with lightningstylesheets = "true". (This needs to stay this way-- when I take that away the whole page doesn't look right.) I need to save this VF page as a PDF to my Lead record, from an after update trigger.

I am seeing that I cannot use renderas="pdf" together with lightningstylesheets="true".

I am also seeing that when I try to save the page as is as a pdf, it does not work-- the logs say

> Internal Salesforce.com Error.

Does anyone have experience with a similar issue? How can I make this work?

Here is the code I'm trying to get the body of the page as pdf:

```
 PageReference pref = Page.SEEK_MVP_PDF_Display;
        pref.getParameters().put('id',leadId);
        Blob b;
if(Test.isRunningTest()) {
  b = blob.valueOf('Unit.Test');
} else {
   b = pref.getContentaspdf(); 
  system.debug('B: ' + b); }
ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
        cv.versionData = b;
        cv.title = 'SEEK Medicare Eligibility Check';
        cv.PathOnClient = 'SEEK_Eligibility_Check.pdf';
        insert cv;
 ContentVersion Content = [SELECT id, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion where Id = :cv.Id];
        ContentDocumentLink contentlink=new ContentDocumentLink();
        contentlink.LinkedEntityId= leadId;
        contentlink.ShareType= 'V';
        contentlink.ContentDocumentId= Content.ContentDocumentId;
        insert contentlink;
```

Comment: This is not strictly an answer... but... Have you tried isolating the markup in a VF component and then creating 2 VF pages (One with the `lightningstylesheets` and one without)? You can use the one without to render as PDF, and maybe write some CSS to make it look better?

Comment: I've tried something similar but it's very hard to make it look as good as it does with lightningstylesheets. I'm racking my brain... is there any possible way to workaround and keep the lightningstylesheets and have it attach as a pdf...

Answer (score 0):

For now, you can't use both. As such, I suggest you toggle it. Here's a self-contained example:

```
<apex:page lightningStylesheets="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.renderAsPdf!='true'}" renderAs="{!if($CurrentPage.parameters.renderAsPdf='true','pdf','')}">
    Hello
</apex:page>
```

Here, if renderAsPdf is true, SLDS is disabled whilst rendering as PDF.

You may want to provide an alternative style sheet when this situation arises. I suspect that the problem is likely that the CSS file for SLDS is too large for the PDF renderer to handle, though I'd have to contact someone that knows the internals better than I to confirm this.

Comment: thank you for this idea. I tried it, and when I display the VF page on my record page it works, but when I try to attach it to my lead record it is still saying Internal Salesforce.com Error. What else would you suggest? Also, is it only renderas pdf that creates an issue- can I render it as any other file type that might honor the slds styling?

Comment: Alternatively what if I create a lightning component that contains the VF page with lightning sheets, then either save that component itself as a pdf, or create a new VF page that contains that component and render that new vf page as a pdf? In your mind, would that work? My thought process is to try and basically take a "screen shot" or image of the original VF page with lightningstylesheets, then display that image on a pdf? Let me know what you think i really appreciate your help!

Comment: @MichaelM You can't save a component as PDF, because it is rendered client-side. You either need either two different style sheets or two entirely different pages, possibly by using a common Visualforce (not Lightning) component.

Comment: In other words, I can have 2 VF pages:
1. with SLDS, without renderas pdf
2. without SLDS, with renderas pdf
and the 2nd page would simply get the contents of the first page. Should that possibly work?

Comment: @MichaelM You can use a Visualforce component to get the same data in to both. See [this help topic](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pages_custom_components.htm&type=5)

Comment: So I'd have to recreate the styling in a visualforce component, then call that in the page, it sounds like. Is there any other way to capture the page as it appears with slds, then display that as a pdf? Any workaround that perhaps captures an image of the page but without using any markup tags that renderas pdf wouldn't conflict with...

Comment: @MichaelM In Visualforce, you may be able to get away with html2pdf, but I haven't tried it. This involves client-side rendering, though, so you couldn't do it from Apex. I don't have a good solution aside from maybe compiling your own stripped down SLDS and importing it directly?

Comment: Interesting. Re. html2pdf, would the way to do it perhaps be to create a static resource with all the css and html markup, call that static resource in a vf page, and renderas pdf?

Re. compiling my own SLDS, whenever I try removing the SLDS and including renderas pdf, and adding my own custom css to the VF page, it seems that the page does not honor any of the CSS.. it seems to just show the raw html/xml.. Why is that/ how can i get that working?

Comment: FYI I found this solution: https://www.eternussolutions.com/2016/08/09/generate-pdf-visualforce-pages-going-beyond-renderas/#comment-363    though it doesn't seem to be working. If I post my vf page code do you think you can tell me what I need to change to make this solution work?

Comment: In case anyone is coming to this page for solution, the way I was able to do this was by keeping renderAs="pdf", and adding my own css by saving the css as a static resource and calling the static resource at the top of the page <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.samplecssSF}"/>, that way the pdf still honored (most of) that css